# Maintenance Plan Failing After Database Collation Change

Tags: sql-server, index, maintenance-plans

We currently use maintenance plans to perform index rebuilds each night (we inherited this system).

Yesterday, i amended to the database collation to match the instance level collation (Latin1_General_CI_AS). Ever since changing the database collation, the maintenance plan fails.

If i go into the maintenance plan and select 'View T-SQL', it errors out with the following message:

> TITLE: Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Cannot resolve collation conflict for column 1 in SELECT statement.
>   Could not use view or function 'sys.all_views' because of binding
>   errors. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 451)

With that said, if i try and rebuild all the indexes just using a T-SQL script, it runs without issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Additionally, I have just found that i cannot expand the system views branch within this database.